# UK Family Visitor Visa Query

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, family

I am a citizen of India and I wish to apply for a family visitor visa for the UK to meet my sister and brother-in-law. My brother-in-law is having a tier 2 residence permit and my sister is on dependent visa.
I am admitted to a university in USA and I am holding a Student visa for USA. I will be going to US directly after meeting them in UK to start my studies and wish to have a stopover in UK for about 3 weeks.

My questions are

1. What documents are required from my brother-in-law's end (He has emailed me an invitation letter, his passport, his residence permit, itinerary plan along with proof of rented apartment at UK)  ?
2. I have been a student all along and therefore I dont have savings in my name. This trip is sponsored by my parents and the UK travel and stay arrangements  are being borne by my brother-in-law. Do I need to still show money in my name/in my account  or is showing the money in my parents account is fine ?
3. Do I need to ask proof of employment from my brother-in-law ?
4. I have already booked tickets for US with a stop-over in UK. Should I submit a copy of the ticket ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. 
I tried applying a fresh visa under Standard Visitor Visa but unfortunately I am not getting that option in the drop-down menu of the website. I am applying for the visa via this website: [link](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/)

Comment: Also, I am trying to show that my father is sponsoring for the expenses at U.K and not my brother-in-law.

In this case what documents will be required from my and my fathers end and also from my brother-in-law's end ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The 'family visitor' programme was abolished in April 2015. Instead you can apply for the [Visitor (standard) Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).

For your questions...

1. He should include all the things you mentioned plus bank statements demonstrating his capacity to sponsor you along with the landlord's permission that you can stay in the flat for 3 weeks;
2. You should submit your own bank account statements. Your parents' statements may not be considered if they are not UK residents.
3. Yes, your BIL should submit his employment contract and salary slips to demonstrate his sponsorship capacity and that his T2 is still valid.
4. No, they do not care about flight tickets.

In general, your BIL acting as economic sponsor should submit everything listed in the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) that would normally be submitted by the applicant.  Note that they will be reluctant to accredit anything submitted by sponsors who are not UK residents.

NOTE: if your BIL's tenancy agreement specifies that visitors staying for 3 weeks are ok, the landlord's permission is not required, but he should submit the tenancy agreement instead.

Comment: @phoog, the law itself is a better reference. Please see Appendix V 4.3 (b)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I am also surprised that by your assertion they would not care about flight tickets.  Wouldn't the ticket help demonstrate (in combination with the student visa) the applicant's intention to leave the UK?

Comment: No it would not

Comment: @phoog UKBA is a very different beast then, maybe EU countries.

Comment: @phoog Air tickets demonstrate _ability_ to leave, not _intent_. In this case I'd think the US student visa and university enrollment would be a far more compelling demonstration of intent to leave the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, well put.  Part of ECO training is that tickets and confirmations do not impute motivation to comply with the rules.